# Usage of nofollow links in AMP

Tags: mobile, nofollow, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

It seems that I want to add a "nofollow" link on Konyalilarserametal.com/amp but "nofollow" links don't work in AMP. Is there any alternative solution for this? [Konya escort](https://konyalilarserametal.com)

I used the "rel="nofollow noopener"" tag, but when I inspected the source code, I saw that this tag is not working.